# Makefile Not Recognizing Object Make Directive

Tags: makefile

I am having issues getting my Makefile to compile a very simple main function, and I can't seem to find the issue. Here is my Makefile:

```
main: main.o Recursion.o
        gcc -Wall -o main main.o Recursion.o

    main.o: main.c Recursion.c
        gcc -Wall -c main.c

    Recursion.o: Recursion.c Recursion.h
        gcc -Wall -c Recursion.c

clean: 
    rm main *.o
```

When I enter the make command in the UNIX terminal, this is the result I get:

```
-bash-4.2$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o Recursion.o Recursion.c
gcc -Wall -o main main.o Recursion.o
main.o: main.c Recursion.c
make: main.o:: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:3: main] Error 127
-bash-4.2$
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong. It is generating the executable main, but I'm not sure what exactly the issue is on the command line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Indentation matters

Comment: You appear to have a TAB at the beginning of the `main.o: ...` line, and probably the `Recursion.o: ...` line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles are indentation-sensitive.

Try this:

```
main: main.o Recursion.o
    gcc -Wall -o main main.o Recursion.o

main.o: main.c Recursion.c
    gcc -Wall -c main.c

Recursion.o: Recursion.c Recursion.h
    gcc -Wall -c Recursion.c

clean: 
    rm main *.o
```